# Choose $x$ objects without replacement from a bag with $n$ object.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

General problem:

Suppose there is a bag containing $n$ items with $m$ unique values $(m \leq n)$.  The distribution of values across all the items is uniform. How many unique values I most probably get if I draw $x$ $(x \leq n)$ items from the bag without replacement?

My concrete problem:

In a relational engine I keep cardinality of a table as well as cardinalities (i.e. number of unique values) of individual columns of the table. When a filter predicate is applied against a particular column (e.g. MyColumn = 'value') I calculate its selectivity factor (e.g. $0.8$) and reduce the table (e.g. from $100$ rows down to $80$ rows). The cardinality of the referenced column in the result is clear ($0.8$ times the original cardinality of the column), but the problem is how to calculate cardinality of each remaining column. Again, I assume uniform distribution of values in every column.

Update:

It turns out my concrete problem is not solved sufficiently by the general question I posed above. It rather should to be described as drawing with replacement. However, I keep the question still available since there are two good answers to the general problem.

Comment: We are assuming that $n=km$ and that each value occurs exactly $k$ times?  Hint:  Let $X_i$ be the indicator for value $i$ (so it is $1$ if value $i$ is drawn, $0$ otherwise).  Easy to compute $E[X_i]$.  But then the value you want is just $E=\sum E[X_i]=mE[X_1]$.

Comment: Or may we assume that we are actually drawing $x$ items from a bag that contains $n$ items of value $1$, plus $n$ items of value 2, .., plus $n$ items of value $m$ ? And that out of the $x$ items you are counting only those which do not have a repeated value ? or are you counting how many different values you obtained?

Comment: @lulu, your assumption is correct. But I'm not sure if I understand your formula correctly. Let me use an example. I have 4 unique values in a 100-item bag. I draw 80 items. Is E[X1] = 1/4? If yes, then E = 1, but I'd expect it to be 4.

Comment: In your example, $E[X_1]$ is a lot greater than $\frac 14$! It is actually impossible for a unique value not to appear in your example (since there are only $20$ items you didn't take).  Therefore $E[X_1]=1$ and $E=4$ as you wanted.

Comment: Ok, can you give me a hint how to compute E[X1] in general?

Comment: Sure (side note:  you have to add the @user if you want the user to get the message directly).  Using your notation, with $n=km$, and say we are drawing $x$.  Let $p$ be the probability that you see value $1$ in the $x$ draws.  Easier to compute $1-p=\frac {(k-1)m}{km}\times \frac {(k-1)m-1}{km-1}\times \cdots \times \frac {(k-1)m-(x-1)}{km-(x-1)}$.  Check that in your example, $1-p=0$.

Comment: Sorry!  On my notepad, I interchanged $k,m$.  My formula ought to read $1-p=\frac {(m-1)k}{mk}\times \frac {(m-1)k-1}{mk-1}\times \cdots \times \frac {(m-1)k-(x-1)}{mk-(x-1)}$.  As a sanity check:  the probability that the first draw is not of value $1$ is clearly $\frac {m-1}m$.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the discussion in the comments:  Indicator variables can be very helpful for problems like these.  Accordingly, let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ value.  Thus $X_i=1$ if your draw of $x$ elements gets one of value $i$, and $X_i=0$ otherwise.  It is easy to compute $E[X_i]$...if $p_i$ denotes the probability that the $i^{th}$ value is drawn then we see that $E[X_i]=p_i$ and $$1-p_i=\frac {(m-1)k}{mk}\times \frac {(m-1)k-1}{mk-1}\times \cdots \times \frac {(m-1)k-(x-1)}{mk-(x-1)}=\frac {(n-k)!(n-x)!}{(n-k-x)!(n!)}$$  Where $m$ is the number of value types, $n=km$ is the total number of items, and $x$ is the number of draws.

The desired answer is then:  $$E=\sum_{i=1}^mE[X_i]=m\left(1-\frac {(n-k)!(n-x)!}{(n-k-x)!(n!)}\right)$$

Note:  it is not difficult to check that this matches the answer given by @MarkoRiedel (I have used $x$ for the number of draws, following the OP, instead of $p$).

Comment: Do you have $x+1$ draws here instead of $x$ in your first formula?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel   I certainly botched something...The denominator of the last fraction ought to be $mk-(x-1)$, is that what you meant?  Got it right in the comments, for what that's worth. I'll edit. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. (+1). I noticed $p$ is not as good a choice as $x$ since it may be mistaken for a probability. For the moment I'll leave it as is.

Comment: @lulu (and Marko), thank you for your answers! I can nicely use the formula for $k$ which is an integer. But it can easily happen that $k$ is a real number. For example when there are $60$ unique values in a $100$-item bag. What can I do in those cases? Do I need to round it?

Comment: Our calculations depend on each value being equally likely (so $k$ is the number of items of a particular value). You can drop that assumption, in which case you need to compute each $E[X_i]$ separately...but otherwise my method works the same way.

Comment: @lulu, I realized I cannot use the formula for multiple draws - draw $x_1$ items first and then draw $x_2$ items out of those $x_1$ items. The problem is that the formula gives different results if I draw $x$ items in different ways: $100 \to 50 \to 30$ vs. $100 \to 80 \to 30$ vs. $100 \to 30$) - I'd like to get the same result. Is this connected to my previous question about the necessity of $k$ being an integer ($k$ usually becomes a real number after the first draw)? I do not see how I could compute $E[X_i]$ after a draw...

Comment: Not sure I am following.  Are you asking:  "how can I compute this expectation by carefully enumerating all the possible combinations?"  If that is your question, then I'd say that the solution posted by @MarkoRiedel is optimal.  At least, I don't see anyway to improve on it.  The beauty of indicator variables is that they sometimes (as here) let you bypass all of that.

Comment: @lulu, I'm not a mathematician so it's hard to follow Marko. I'd like to understand primarily one thing: Is it possible to say that $n = km$ while having $k$ a real number? And if yes, is it still valid to numerically calculate the expectation based on the formula above (using gamma function)?

Comment: Still not sure I am following.  If $m$ does not divide $k$ evenly, then some values must be more probable than others.  That's fine...my method can be extended to that case, you just need to compute each $E[X_i]$ separately. There would be no Gamma functions involved.  But perhaps I am not understanding.

Comment: @lulu, let's say that $n=100$, $m=20$, $k=5$ and $x=50$. The values are obviously distributed evenly. The formula gives the result: $E=19.4$. Let's say that the drawn items form a new bag ($n=50$, $m=19.4$). Are the unique values of the new bag still distributed evenly? Now if I draw from the new bag, what will be $E$? Thanks for being patient with me!

Comment: How can there be $19.4$ unique values?  Remember, oftentimes the "expected outcome" of a game is not a possible outcome. If I throw a fair die, the expected number of dots is $3.5$, even though it is actually not possible to get $3.5$ dots.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have $n$ items of $m$ types where $n=km.$ We draw $p$ items
and ask about the expected value  of the number of distinct items that
appear.

First  compute  the total  count  of  possible configurations.  The
species here is

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=m}(\mathfrak{P}_{\le k}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the EGF 
$$G_0(z) = \left(\sum_{q=0}^k \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)^m.$$

The count of configurations is then given by (compute this as a sanity
check)

$$p! [z^p] G_0(z).$$

Note however  that in  order to account  for the probabilities  we are
missing  a  multinomial coefficient  to represent  the  configurations
beyond $p.$ If a  set of size $q$ was chosen for  a certain type among
the   first    $p$   elements   that   leaves    $k-q$   elements   to
distribute. Therefore we introduce

$$G_1(z) = \left(\sum_{q=0}^k \frac{z^q}{q! (k-q)!}\right)^m.$$

The desired quantity is then given by

$$(n-p)! p! [z^p] G_1(z)
= (n-p)! p! \frac{1}{(k!)^m} [z^p] 
\left(\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} z^q\right)^m
\\ = (n-p)! p! [z^p] \frac{1}{(k!)^m} (1+z)^{km}
= {n\choose p} \frac{1}{(k!)^m} (n-p)! p!
\\ = \frac{n!}{(k!)^m}$$

The  sanity  check goes  through.   What we  have  done  here in  this
introductory  section  is   classify  all  ${n\choose  k,k,\ldots  k}$
combinations  according to  some fixed  value of  $p,$  extracting the
information of the  distribution of values among the  first $p$ items.
We should of course get all of them when we do this, and indeed we do.

Now we  need to mark zero size  sets.  The count of  zero size sets
counts the types that are not present.  We get the EGF

$$H(z,u) = \left(\frac{u}{k!}
+ \sum_{q=1}^k \frac{z^q}{q! (k-q)!}\right)^m.$$

For the count of the  number of types  that are not  present we
thus obtain

$$(n-p)! p! [z^p]
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} H(z, u)\right|_{u=1}.$$

We have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} H(z, u)
= m \left(\frac{u}{k!}
+ \sum_{q=1}^k \frac{z^q}{q! (k-q)!}\right)^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}$$

Evaluate this at $u=1$ to get

$$\frac{m}{k!} 
\left(\sum_{q=0}^k \frac{z^q}{q! (k-q)!}\right)^{m-1}.$$

Extracting coefficients yields

$$\frac{m}{k!} (n-p)! p!  
[z^p] \frac{1}{(k!)^{m-1}}
\left(\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} z^q\right)^{m-1}
\\ = \frac{m}{k!} (n-p)! p!  
[z^p] \frac{1}{(k!)^{m-1}} (1+z)^{km-k}
\\ = {n-k\choose p} m (n-p)! p!  
\frac{1}{(k!)^{m}}.$$

Therefore the expectation turns out to be

$$m - m {n-k\choose p} {n\choose p}^{-1}
= m \left(1 - {n-k\choose p} {n\choose p}^{-1}\right).$$

**Remark.** The  simplicity of this  answer is evident and  an elegant
and straightforward probabilistic argument is sure to appear.

**Remark II.**  For any remaining  sceptics and those seeking  to know
more about  the probability model used  here I present  the Maple code
for this work, which includes total enumeration as well as the formula
from  above. Routines  ordered  according to  efficiency and  resource
consumption.

```
with(combinat);

Q :=
proc(m, k, p)
option remember;
local n, perm, items, dist, res;

    n := m*k;

    items :=
    [seq(seq(r, q=1..k), r=1..m)];

    res := 0;

    for perm in permute(items) do
        dist :=
        convert([seq(perm[q], q=1..p)], `set`);

        res := res + nops(dist);
    od;

    res/(n!/(k!)^m);
end;


QQ :=
proc(m, k, p)
option remember;
local n, perm, items, dist, rest, res;

    n := m*k;

    items :=
    [seq(seq(r, q=1..k), r=1..m)];

    res := 0;

    for perm in choose(items, p) do
        dist := convert(perm, `set`);

        rest := p!* (n-p)!
        /mul(q[2]!*(k-q[2])!,
             q in convert(perm, `multiset`));

        rest := rest/(k!)^(m-nops(dist));

        res := res + rest*nops(dist);
    od;

    res/(n!/(k!)^m);
end;

X :=
proc(m, k, p)
local n;

    n := m*k;
    m*(1-binomial(n-k,p)/binomial(n,p));
end;
```